# Dataframe - get column name from list of variables, in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a list `hikari_col` which has a two values: `column_name1`, `column_name2`.
I also have a dataframe `df1` which contains this values as column names. 
I'm trying to check a values from `df1` dataframe based on that `hikari_col` list. So I'm passing a values from list in `for` loop as a column in dataframe and checking if it throws an error or not.

```py
hikari_cols = ["column_name1", "column_name2"]
df1 = create_dfs("hikari", hikari_cols) # creating a df in another function
    for hikari_col in hikari_cols: # looping over values in list (same as column names in df1)
        try:
            df1.hikari_col # Checking if column was created - It is, and its available as `df1.column_name1`
        except:            # But not as df1.hikari_col
            return err_dict = {"error": "not found"}
```

But it goes to exception every time. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is create_dfs() a function that you created? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `.` doesn't work with strings, you have to change `df.hikari_col` to `df[hikari_col]`, but the most efficient way would be:

```
hikari_cols = ["column_name1", "column_name2"]
df1 = create_dfs("hikari", hikari_cols) # creating a df in another function
if any(i not in df1.columns for i in hikari_cols):
    err_dict = {"error": "not found"}
```

Comment: thanks! this worked! Just delete one `in` in your code